# Which is better "4+" or "+4"?

Tags: numerals, syntax

I am writing a document with a list of accomplishments and want to indicate that I did something at least 4 times.  It was definitely more than just 4 instances, but I can only recall 4 specific instances.  I also do not want to waste precious space or be overly wordy by saying "at least 4" or "more than 4."

As such, I have want to use either "4+" or "+4".
Which one of these is correct or better to use?  I believe that I have seen both used, but I'm not sure which is better.

Answer (score 2):

*4+* means "more than four"

*+4* means "four more"

Since you want to say "at least four", you should choose *4+*.

Comment: I don't think "+4" has any general interpretation, it should just be avoided in most contexts. You might write a note for someone to "please get 4+ apples" instructing them to get at least 4 apples. I'd have no idea what would be intended by the note "please get +4 apples", I would not interpret it as a request to get exactly 4 more apples.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie (1) "Pls buy 5  for the cake +4 for the fruit salad!" (2) " Would +4, if possible, I totally agree with your answer!" (3) "This lens has a +4 diopter correction." (4) etc.

Comment: You're kind of proving my point. #1 is read "Please buy 5 apples for the cake and 4 more for the fruit salad." It's simply using + to mean "and". I'm not sure how #2 should be pronounced, possibly as "add" or "plus". In #3, it's a "plus 4 diopter". The pronunciation varies, and is not "4 more" in any of those examples.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie In all my examples *+4* means "four more": "...and four more apples for the cake"; "I'd like to give your answer four more upvotes than it already has"; "the glasses add four more diopters to the focal length of 60 diopters that your eyes have naturally". You can of course phrase that differently, if you prefer, but that doesn't change the meaning. *5 + 4* means "five and four more".

Comment: @NuclearHoagie In a follow up message to "We need flour, eggs and five apples", "please get +4 apples" could mean something like: "Please get **four more** apples than I told you. I forgot that we also need some for the fruit salad."